# gcc compiling .c with .s file - .bss confusion (bug?)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

Using gcc 4.6.3 under Ubuntu 12.04 on an IA32 architecture, I ran into an issue relating to compiling C files with assembly files using storage on the .bss segment with both .comm and .lcomm directives.

Between a .comm and a .lcomm buffer, the assembly file foo.s uses close to the maximum space gas lets me allocate in this segment (foo calculates prime factorization of long longs). With an assembly file bar.s handling i/o and such, everything compiles and links fine (and fast), and works well.

When I then use a C file bar.c to handle i/o, gcc does not terminate - or at least not in less than 5 minutes. The .bss request is close to my small notebook memory, but as the .bss segment does not get compile-time initialized, and as it works with bar.s, I don't see why this happens.

When I reduce the .bss size requested in foo.s, gcc compiles and links fine, and everything executes as it should. Also, as expected, the file size of the executable created in each case using

```
   gcc bar.c foo.s -Wall
```

*does not depend on the size in .bss requested* (I compiled varying sizes which were all much smaller than the original, failing size).  The executable is very small (maybe 10k) in all cases - in fact, of identical size - except, obviously, the original case which does not successfully compile and gets hung up.

Is this a gcc bug? Is there a command line option to use to prevent this from happening? Or what is going on?

Edit: per a comment, here is the part with the .bss segment allocation:

```
# Sieve of Eratosthenes
# Create list of prime numbers smaller than n
#
# Note: - no input error (range) check
#       - n <= 500,000,000 (could be changed) - in assembly
#         compiling it with gcc: trouble. make n <= 50,000,000
# Returns: pointer to array of ints of prime numbers
#          (0 sentinel at end)
#
# Registers: %esi: sentinel value (n+1)
#            %edx: n
#            %ecx: counting variable (2 - n)
#            %ebx: pointer into array of primes
#                  (position next to be added)
#            %eax: inner pointer to A. tmp array
    .section .bss
#   .lcomm tmp_Arr, 2000000008  # 500,000,000 plus sentinel & padding
#   .comm prime_Arr, 500000008 # asymptotically, primes aren't dense
    .lcomm tmp_Arr, 200000008  # 50,000,000 plus sentinel & padding
    .comm prime_Arr, 50000008 # asymptotically, primes aren't dense

    .section .text
    .globl sieve
     .type sieve, @function
sieve:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx
    pushl %esi
    pushl %ebx  

    # create Eratosthenes tmp array
    movl $0, %ecx
loop_sieve_Tmp_:    
    movl %ecx, tmp_Arr(, %ecx, 4)
    addl $1, %ecx
    cmp %ecx, %edx
    jge loop_sieve_Tmp_

    # initialize registers used in algorithm
    movl $2, %ecx   # outer loop counting var
    movl %ecx, %eax # inner loop counting var
    xor %ebx, %ebx  # pointer to prime array
    movl %edx, %esi
    incl %esi       # sentinel (or placeholder for 'not prime')
 loop_sieve_Outer_:
    movl %ecx, prime_Arr(, %ebx, 4)  # record prime
    incl %ebx
 loop_sieve_Inner_:
    addl %ecx, %eax
    movl %esi, tmp_Arr(, %eax, 4)
    cmp %eax, %edx
    jge loop_sieve_Inner_
 find_Next_:    # find minimum in Erist. tmp array
    addl $1, %ecx
    cmp %ecx, %edx
    jl lbl_sieve_done_
    cmp tmp_Arr(, %ecx, 4), %esi
    je find_Next_

    movl %ecx, %eax
    jmp loop_sieve_Outer_
 lbl_sieve_done_:
    movl $0, prime_Arr(, %ebx, 4)       # sentinel
    movl $prime_Arr, %eax

    popl %ebx
    popl %esi
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
 # end sieve
```

Comment: Can you include some extracts from the source files? Is there anything especially unusual in them?

Comment: @duskwuff: I added the part with the .bss segment allocation. The prime factorization file (still polishing it) is getFactors.s, the one handling i/o testFactor.s at https://github.com/RalfMBecker/Euler (the C file allocates two local (automatic) arrays of integers, size 10 each, declares one long long n (also local), and calls getFactor() per the signature in the .s file, then prints the factors (as said, all works fine when using smaller size). I didn't put the C file on github as it's really nothing special - 10 lines in a main() maybe; all variables local/stack.

Comment: I wonder if the C runtime explicitly writes 0 to the entire `.bss` section at startup so it ends up thrashing the paging on your notebook? When you use nothing by assembly, you might be avoiding the runtime's initialization of `.bss`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes, I agree. Something like this must be going on - not necessarily explicit inicialization, but maybe marking memory segments as inaccessible - even, apparently, to the compiler trying to compile. As the file size later shrinks to what is expected, something is going on temporarily that makes compiling otherwise perfectly legitimate code (for all I can tell...) not compile. Not really a bug (if it is), but an unnecessary inconvenience hitting in edge cases.

Comment: @gnometorule: oh - I didn't realize that this was about a problem that was happening at compile/link time (as well as at runtime?). I just thought that maybe the C runtime was  writing a zero to each location from `.bss` start to `.bss` end.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: No, I don't even get to see the runtime: when I compile with the commented out sizes, the compile command in the question gets hung (I killed it after some minutes, so not sure if it would ever return). When I talk about the executable having "same size regardless the .bss amount requested", that was for smaller sizes requested to compare.

Comment: If you are asking for 2.5GB of .bss space on a 32bit machine, I'm not surprised things aren't working.  You're awfully close to the virtual memory limit, and maybe there is a bug in gcc that can't handle static allocation above 1GB or so. What happens if you call `malloc` to dynamically allocate the memory?

Comment: @MarkLakata: that would be beside the point of the question though - it's about understanding behavior in the bss I cannot reconcile (given the different treatment of heap and bss, this would be an entirely different question).

Comment: It seems like a bug in gcc for sure, and using the heap might be a work around. try a newer version of gcc, like 4.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replicated your problem with gcc 4.7.2 on Debian. It doesn't hang for me, but it does take a substantial length of time (10 seconds).

It appears that the linker actually allocates and zeros "comm" memory during it's processing. If the machine is sufficiently memory limited (as it seems yours is) this will cause the linker to thrash the swap even though the final executable will be tiny. For me the memory allocation was around 2.3Gb.

I tried a couple of variations (.space, .zero, .org) and they all seem to give the same effect.

With an up to date version on the compiler (4.9) this no longer happens.